# Laravel: Sum Collection by Custom Method

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a model that has a custom method (assume it has a field called 'fieldname')
e.g.

```
class X extends \Eloquent 
{
    function custommethodtest()
       {
           return rand(1);
       }
}
```

I want to use the collection and SUM by the custom method ie:

```
 X:all()->sum('custommethodtest');
```

but it appears that laravel will only sum by an actual field, not a custom method. For instance, this would work:

```
X::all()->sum('fieldname');
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: if you wish to return custommethodtest as a custom table fieldname (attribute) then you can define an accessor

Comment: please we need a feedback. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just a method, create an [attribute accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators):

```
public function getCustommethodtestAttribute(){
    return rand();
}
```

And then:

```
X:all()->sum('custommethodtest');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use custom attribute to achieve same result;

```
class X extends \Eloquent 
{
    protected $appends = [
        'custom_test'
    ];

    public function getCustomTestAttribute()
    {
        //NB: rand() expects exactly 2 parameters, am using 1234 for parameter 2 just for testing sake
        return $this->attributes['custom_test'] = rand(1,1234);
    }
}
```

Then:

`X:all()->sum('custom_test');`

The method above better than using only:

```
public function getCustomTestAttribute(){
  return rand(1);
}
```

For this reason:

> Once the attribute has been added to the appends list, it will be
>   included in both the model's array and JSON forms. Attributes in the
>   appends array respect the visible and hidden configuration on the
>   model.

Comment: If the attribute isn't needed in array and JSON representation, appending it has no benefit. And that's up the OP to decide. It's not *"better"*

Comment: Also setting the attribute in an attribute accessor is unnecessary. It will be cached automatically

Comment: @lukasgeiter You are right Sir, if its not needed in array and JSON, however I believe in this scenario custom_test should be treated like a fieldname like the question suggested and not just a method